# How do I run Jmeter test from command line with -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=IP and command line parameter?

Tags: command-line, jmeter, parameter-passing, rmi, distributed-testing

I need to run a distributed test with some of the command line parameter and also I need to pass My server IP with -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=IP, since I am running it from the command line I need nee to give as

`jmeter -n -t C:\\Jmxfile.jmx -r Gsomeproperty=value` in command line.

I am confused of passing even the command line parameter and also hostname? can somebody help me in sending both at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override):

> Java system properties and JMeter properties can be overridden directly on the command line (instead of modifying jmeter.properties). To do so, use the following options:
>
> -D[prop_name]=[value]
>   defines a java system property value.
>
> -J[prop_name]=[value]
>   defines a local JMeter property.
>
> -G[prop_name]=[value]
>   defines a JMeter property to be sent to all remote servers.
>
> -G[propertyfile]
>   defines a file containing JMeter properties to be sent to all remote servers.

So, you can send both at a time through the command line.

Comment: you mean like   jmeter -n -t C:\\Jmxfile.jmx -r -Gsomeproperty=value -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=IP